# Почему присвоить элемент массиву вне метода Start некорректно?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я изучаю C# и Unity, возник вопрос.

Предположим мы создаем пустой массив с фиксированным объемом. Затем присваиваем значение элементу массива.
**Вопрос:** Почему присвоение некорректно сделать вне метода Start?

То есть почему так правильно:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChaikaLetit : MonoBehaviour {

    string[] names = new string[5];

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        names [0] = "Jessie";
        print ("First name is "+names[0]);
    }
}
```

А так нет:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChaikaLetit : MonoBehaviour {

    string[] names = new string[5];
    names [0] = "Jessie";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        print ("First name is "+names[0]);
    }
}
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: потому что это ошибка синтаксиса C#. Использовать поля можно только внутри методов свойств или конструкторов. Кстати был уже подобный вопрос, надо поискать

Comment: Вопрос никак не относится к Юнити. Поэтому я бы вам рекомендовал для начала изучить C#

Comment: @Grundy Но при этом если мы задаем значения элементов сразу во время создания массива `string[] names = new string[]{"Jessie"};`  это не считается "использованием" уже созданного поля, поэтому корректно, верно?

Comment: @Rumata, да, это все входит в _инициализацию_ поля

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не был уверен, не связано ли это именно с тем как Unity интерпретирует C#.

Comment: @Grundy Понятно, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Grundy Не до конца понимаю пример в другом вопросе, по-моему там речь о том как правильно объявлять классы?..

Comment: @Rumata, нет, там суть в том, что в книжке в примере была ошибка: в теле класса было не только объявление поля но и его использование, как у тебя в вопросе.

Comment: @Grundy Ок, спасибо, тогда все верно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# так сделать нельзя, но можно так:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChaikaLetit : MonoBehaviour {

   string[] names = new string[5]
        {
         "Jessie",
         "name 2 ",
         "name 3",
         "name 4",
         "name 5"
        };

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        print ("First name is "+names[0]);
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/library/0a7fscd0.aspx

Объясню не научно, но по-простому: вне функций в C# можно только объявлять и инициализировать переменные, при этом names[0] =  "Jessie"; Это уже обращение к элементу массива.

---

Но если рассматривать Unity, то в ней не рекомендованы конструкторы, по этому массив из Unity-типов придется инициализировать либо в редакторе либо в функции Awake/Start, иначе Unity может выдать ошибку/предупреждение.